# Golang cassandra gocql transaction need a delay time to executed

Tags: go, cassandra, cql, gocql

This block of code does not delete the data, I don't know why.

```
s.Query(
        "INSERT INTO smth (id, name) VALUES (?,?)",
        data.ID
        data.Name
    ).ScanCAS(nil, nil, nil)

s.Query(
    "DELETE FROM smth WHERE id = ? AND name = ?",
    data.ID
    data.Name
).Exec()
```

but if I added some delay like so:

```
s.Query(
        "INSERT INTO smth (id, name) VALUES (?,?)",
        data.ID
        data.Name
    ).ScanCAS(nil, nil, nil)

time.Sleep(time.Second)
s.Query(
    "DELETE FROM smth WHERE id = ? AND name = ?",
    data.ID
    data.Name
).Exec()
```

The data will be deleted.

Does anyone know how to fix it without adding the delay?
I'm using `github.com/gocql/gocql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gocql queries are executed asynchronously](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocql/gocql#hdr-Executing_multiple_queries_concurrently) so there are no guarantees that your `DELETE` is executed *after* the `INSERT`.

In any case, your test case is invalid because *immediately deleting* a partition after it has just been inserted isn't a valid use case.

As a side note, your code appears to be wrong to me. You are calling `Query.ScanCAS()` when you insert data but the query isn't a lightweight transaction -- it's missing the conditional `IF EXISTS`/`IF NOT EXISTS`. Cheers!